# Interactive Forms (Indd > PDF) Placeholder text in interactive form text field

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat, forms, interactive

I do not believe that placeholder text (populated in a form's text field before PDF export) is currently an option. Anyone know any workarounds (bar manual inputting via Acrobat). Surprisingly, it doesn't appear to be an option in Acrobat's Rich Media tools either.

Just in case I'm not clear - here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

I've set up my form in INDD and created a text field underneath "Date"
[image: Form layout]

Ideally this field would contain predefined guide notes for the user; in this case the date 'zeroed out'
[image: List item]

Unfortunately this text disappears when exported or - if I overtyped - it would move for the user.
[image: List item] (Field is highlighted without text)

Any ideas?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is here in this video thanks to Neil Malek:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUrtYQGNyQE&ab_channel=NeilMalek

The video adds a script for an action **On Focus**:

```
if(event.target.value==event.target.defaultValue) event.target.value="";
```

And also you can add two other actions for when your field is Left empty to get filled with default field's text again:

script for **On Blur** and **Mouse Exit** actions:

```
if(event.target.value=="")event.target.value=event.target.defaultValue ;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use the placeholder text as default, and then add a little bit of logic to make it disappear when the field has the focus, and reappear when it loses it, and the value has not changed.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Max. Would this be via the SHOW/HIDE action then?

Comment: It would use event.value, event.valueEx, and event.target.value; you can't show/hide, because to enter something, the field has to be visible…